# Managing django powered websites

Tags: django, deployment, server, ubuntu-16.04

A while ago I decided to set up my own website that I could use for learning purposes. At the beginning I only needed to try out stuff that can be handled via terminal, but now when I want to get some actual html/js/django stuff going on, I need more efficient way to manage files and write code.

I currently have droplet in Digitalocean with Ubuntu 16.04 image, Apache 2.4.18. and Django 1.11 for backend logic.

So, my problem is that I don't know efficient way to deploy code that's in my machine, to the server.
The ideal situation for me is that I could run, test and modify my django app locally, and then commit/push the changes to server if the code is ok.

I tried to workaround the problem by downloading WinSCP and then just copying the project directory into my local machine. Not only did it take more than 20 minutes, but I wasn't able to make it run locally because of Django import error. To clarify, I have Django and all the other stuff installed inside avirtualenv.

Any tips?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to copy over your entire virtualenv. Rather, you should create a virtualenv on the server and install the dependencies directly.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out, though just wanted to try if it would work

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to approach this, two of the more popular methods would be Git and Subversion.  Both can be used with a GUI or from the command line via a terminal emulator such as PuTTy.  WinSCP, a fine program, is, as you have realized, a tool mostly for ftp.

The concept I recommend you embrace is "Version Control".   Research Git and GitHub, as well as Subversion and TortoiseSVN.  There are others!